# how to create receive {} block in scala with no arguments

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I want to have nice code as following in scala:

```
class MyClass {
    receive {
      case DoThis => println("dothis")
      case DoThat => println("dothat")
    }
}
```

now I understand receive should be a partial function, but no matter which partial function i created it didn't work.  Which partial function should I be creating for this `receive` with `noarg` code to be working.

Or in other words which code block should I be adding to MyClass so that I can call it with

```
new MyClass().receive(DoThis) // which code to add to MyClass so that can call receive like this
```

thanks

Comment: Er, why should receive be a partial function?  Are you trying to use this with actors?  If you are calling it like a method (not how you use actors), why don't you use `def` or `val` in front of `receive` (i.e. make it a method or function)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a `PartialFunction` you have to specify its type like this:

```
sealed trait DoParent
case object DoThis extends DoParent
case object DoThat extends DoParent

{
  case DoThis => println("dothis")
  case DoThat => println("dothat")
}: PartialFunction[DoParent, Unit]
```

Now you can assign this partial function (instance of `PartialFunction[DoParent, Unit]`) to variable or field like this:

```
val receive: PartialFunction[DoParent, Unit] = {
  case DoThis => println("dothis")
  case DoThat => println("dothat")
}

receive(DoThis)
// dothis
```